# Using svn switch inside trunk

Tags: svn

I have a project that contains a lot of data in addition to the source code, i.e., there is a large `project` directory with a small `source` directory inside. I would like to create branches of the `source` directory, but so far nobody in the project used branches, so there is no "trunk". I am wondering if the following approach would work, or if there could be any problems:

```
project$ mkdir branches
project$ svn cp source branches/mybranch
project$ cd source
project/source$ svn switch ^/project/branches/mybranch
# Work with branch...
project/source$ svn commit
# Back to "trunk"...
project/source$ svn switch ^/project/source
```

I tested this with a separate SVN repository, and it seems to work. However, things like the last line above or something like

```
# Merge trunk into branch.
project/source$ svn merge ^/project/source
```

look a little dangerous.

Comment: Since all branches will be checked out with the project anyways, I'm thinking that it's probably safer to just work in `branches/mybranch` directly instead of using `svn switch` on the "trunk", i.e., on `project/source`.